# Cómo crear y usar nombres de variables dinámicamente en PHP

Tags: php

He estado intentando hacer una variable dinámica que cambie cada vez que se recorre el bucle. Para ello he puesto un acumulador que modifica la variable, pero tengo un problema y es que la variable no se deja modificar.  Me pone problemas por el igual que esta seguido y necesito que cada que pase por allí, la variable sea diferente.

```
include("con_db.php");

$registros = mysqli_query($con, "select link from productos") or
    die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));

$numero=0;

while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
    $numero=$numero+1;
    $numero."imag1"=$reg['link'] . "<br>";
}

echo$1imag1;
echo$1imag2;

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable no puede empezar por un número, pero puedes hacerlo al revés, poniendo el número al final. Una vez construido el nombre de la variable, puedes acceder a la misma usando **doble `$`**. Creo que lo entenderás con este ejemplo:

```
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
    $numero++;
    $var = "imag1_" . $numero; //Creo un nombre de variable dinámicamente
    $$var = $reg['link'] . "<br>"; //Con $$ accedo al nombre de variable dinámico
}

echo $imag1_1;
echo $imag1_2;
```

El problema que veo al hacer los `echo` ahí es que no sabes si realmente se ha definido $imag1_2, mejor tendrías que volver a usar un bucle:

```
for ($c = 0; $c <= $numero; $c++) {
    $var = "imag1_" . $c;
    echo $var;
}
```

Así que realmente pienso que te iría mejor utilizar un `array` donde ir guardando los valores, en vez de crear variables dinámicamente:

```
$arr = array();

while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
    $arr[] = $reg['link'] . "<br>";
}

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Por último, no sé para qué quieres los valores, pero si es para hacer los `echo` como en el ejemplo, entonces te sobra almacenar los datos para luego volver a recorrerlos, puedes usarlos (en este caso hacer los `echo`) directamente dentro del bucle `while`.

```
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
    echo $reg['link'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Huy hermano esta fue la mejor opción felicitaciones y mi y mil gracias. ,muy agradecido.

Comment: Acepta la respuesta entonces ;)

Answer (score 0):

Las variables no deben iniciar con números. Revisa la [documentación de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.basics.php).

Si lo que necesitas es mostrar en pantalla un listado con la información que te devuelve la consulta, será suficiente con pasar `echo` dentro del ciclo.

```
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
    echo ($reg['link'] . "<br>");
}
```

En caso de no funcionar con `<br>`, puedes probar con el símbolo `\n`

```
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
    echo ($reg['link'] . "\n");
}
```

O puedes utilizar la constante predefinida `PHP_EOL`

```
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
    echo ($reg['link'].PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesito que en cada ejecución la variable cambien   para poder usar esa variable para algo que necesito en si. En realidad lo que necesito es una variable que se valla cambiando de nombre cada que se ejecute un bucle independientemente de un while o de un for.

Comment: Entonces lo que necesitas es un `array`.